# Как правильно использовать Build.VERSION.SDK_INT в android?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

В android для разных версий SDK есть свои библиотеки.
К примеру с версии SDK >= 21 устарела

> android.hardware.Camera

и появилась

> android.hardware.camera2

Выходит, что код нужно дублировать для устройств SDK < 21 и SDK >=21. Неужели весь код нужно оборачивать в условия?

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=21) {
// первая версия кода
} else {
// вторая версия кода
}
```

Может быть есть другие, более подходящие способы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я вот например так использовал:

```
private void setAlarm(int delayInMillis, PendingIntent sender){
    final int SDK_INT = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    long timeInMillis = (System.currentTimeMillis() + delayInMillis) / 1000 * 1000;     //> example
    if (SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, sender);
    }
    else if (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= SDK_INT  && SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, sender);
    }
    else if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, sender);
    }
}
```

Для разных версий методы по разному вызываются или делают что-то другое при том же способе вызова. С камерой принцип тот же. Думаю можно написать отдельный универсальный класс который охватит эти 2 камеры и в коде использовать уже его.

Comment: А нельзя для разных версий SDK код разделять полностью? чтобы получилось как бы 2 разных приложения?

Comment: @МаксимЖелезняков можно, только на уровне логики, как и описано выше.
Создаете класс-хелпер, который знает о версиях и к какой какую реализацию использовать.